# form submit show inputs on url on html

Tags: html

I have a login problem in html part, when I submit the inputs it gives on url like this

> http://website/home/index.html?username=jk&password=jn

so it doesnt login

```
<form  action="login.php" method="post"> 
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="tb-login-user text-center" placeholder="Username"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="tb-login-user text-center" placeholder="Password"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><input type="submit" value="Login"  class="member-button"></div>
            </form>
```

I looked for already solved problems however they didnt work. I will 
appreciate for your help

Comment: Is impossible that this code sends to same page with GET parameters. You must share the complete code, maybe a javascript that makes conflict

Answer (score 1):

this might be old but I hope it benefits someone,
I had the same problem when I was using a ready Bootstrap template
it worked when I deleted the class named

```
".jumbotron"
```

take your form out of the divs or classes one by one until you find the problem..